# Input cambia de color

Tags: html, css

Tengo unos `input` con estas propiedades:

```css
input {
  font-family: "Latin Modern Roman 10";
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: black !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holo">
  <input type="text" name="Extension" id="Extension" placeholder="Extension" required="required"/>
</div>
```

Esta dentro de un formulario,cuando ingreso un dato escribiéndolo, el color de fondo de la casa es gris, como lo tengo, pero si le doy click al input me muestra los datos que ya he ingresado, si doy click a uno de esos datos, el color de fondo del input se vuelve azul, necesito que se quede del mismo gris que ya le tengo.

Comment: Hola, el código compartido en la pregunta no es suficiente para ver el problema que describes. Edita la pregunta para añadir todo el código relevante (lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información).

Comment: Ya le agregue el codigo del input, no hay mas codigo, yo creo que con que la leas entenderas que pido.

Comment: Dale al botón de ejecutar que aparece en la pregunta. Pulsando en el input el fondo no se vuelve azul (ni es gris de inicio), debe haber otro código (CSS o JS) que esté afectando y que sin verlo es imposible ayudarte. Es por eso que te comentaba que hace falta añadir más información/código a la pregunta. Tal y como está ahora, el problema no se puede reproducir.

Comment: si mira, ingresa un dato y veras que el fondo de la caja se queda como azul celeste, eso es lo que me pase en mi formulario, el formulario es gris y al ingresar un dato se convierte de ese color celeste

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente hayan otras reglas con elementos `input` que predominan a las que tú necesitas.

Pon tus reglas `input` más específicas, agregándole una clase o ID a tu formulario.

```
form.clase_formulario input {
    /* tus reglas*/
}
```

```
form#id_formulario input {
    /* tus reglas*/
}
```

y/o agregando el tipo de los inputs

```
form#id_formulario input[type=text], form#id_formulario textarea {
    /* tus reglas*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no se si lo pudiste solucionar pero estuve buscando varios días como cambiar eso mismo.
Yo estoy usando angular material lo puede cambiar de la siguiente forma.
cree un id para el form

```
#idForm {
   /*color de outline cuando estas parado sobre el input*/
  .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: $color;
  }

  /*color de titulo cuando estas parado sobre el input*/
  .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo estuve peleando bastante con esto y me funcionó hacerlo de esta manera:

`.form-login input:-webkit-autofill{ box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset; }`

form-login es una clase que tiene el formulario, y claramente estaría seleccionando todos los inputs de ese formulario. Espero que les sirva, saludos